# How to reset timeout function after checking a condition which is running by drag and drop in jQuery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to reset timeout function after checking a particular number.

I am having a `droppable` box, where I am dropping some draggable `li`. I have set a time for 10 seconds in a `timeout` function.

I want to check if dropped li number is greater than 5, `timeout` function will reset again.

In this way I want to continue, if my users completed each five number within every 10 seconds, he / she will get another 10 seconds to continue, if he/ she fails to complete within this time, a message will appear.

Here is a fiddle link :

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <ul class='lists'>
 <li>01</li>
 <li>02</li>
 <li>03</li>
 <li>04</li>
 <li>05</li>
 <li>06</li>
 <li>07</li>
 <li>08</li>
 <li>09</li>
 <li>10</li>
 </ul>
  <div class="dropbox">
      drop here
  </div>
  <div class="timeover">
   time over
   </div>
 </div>


 // ------------------- script -------------------
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var timeframe = 10000;
   // ----------- draggable -------------
  $(".lists li").draggable({
    revert:true
  });
  // -------------- drop function ------------
  $(".dropbox").droppable({
    drop: function () {
   // -------------
     var dragelem = $('.ui-draggable-dragging');
     $(dragelem).addClass('dropped');
     var scoreCard = $(".dropped").length;
   }
 });
 setTimeout(function(){
        $('.timeover').addClass('show');
 },timeframe);
});
```

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/subhajit06/0cyos3kj/)

If you have any other solution for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign your timeOut to some variable and then you can:

```
var timerId = setTimeout(...);
clearTimeout(timerId);
```

It's a half from you needed but then you can reassign it again or do other stuff